# Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range

Tags: rigging

whenever I press the GENERATE RIG option in blender.....this error shows up....I really cant find its solution.....So much time wasted on it but really cant find a single clue about it....someone please tell the solution.

> Following error at the bottom of the blender

```
     "Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range".
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any hint for solving that?